# Delete polygon underlap?

Tags: qgis, polygon, grass-gis, vector, topology

I am editing a layer in QGIS with severe polygon overlaps. Is there a way to delete the underlapping portions (i.e. the invisible parts) using QGIS?

If I import the layer into GRASS using the GRASS-plugin, I can get a very useful layer which contains the overlaps (polygons_2), but if I use the difference geoprocessing tool to slice the overlaps from the original file, it naturally cuts away the overlap as well as the underlap, leaving holes instead of overlaps. I have also tried the v.clean functions in grass, but the overlaps are really too big to use snapping without distorting the data.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend SAGA `Polygon self-intersection` tool.

Image below is a single polygon layer, with multiple overlapping features (polygons). (`Dodge` blending mode is used to highlight overlaps, but it is simply green in normal display).

[image]

1. Activate `Polygon self-intersection` tool from `QGIS Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Vector polygon tools`.
2. Set `id` or any field to represent each polygon feature to `identifier` and hit `[Run]`.

[image]

Done. All those overlapping (or underlapping) parts are now removed.